# Binding nested JSON data to list view in SAP UI5

Tags: listview, data-binding, sapui5

I wanted to bind below JSON data to SAP UI5 List view. The view is in XML format. Same data is being used to create Tree view. Please suggest me if there is any working example to get this done.

```js
[{
  "text": "Node1",
  "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-audio",
  "nodes": [{
    "text": "Node1-1",
    "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-e-pub",
    "nodes": [{
        "text": "Node1-1-1",
        "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-html"
      },
      {
        "text": "Node1-1-2",
        "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-photo",
        "nodes": [{
          "text": "Node1-1-1",
          "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-text-file",
          "nodes": [{
              "text": "Node1-1-1-1",
              "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-video"
            },
            {
              "text": "Node1-1-1-2",
              "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-zip-file"
            },
            {
              "text": "Node1-1-1-3",
              "ref": "sap-icon://course-program"
            }
          ]
        }]
      }
    ]
  }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the sample on sapui5 on demand?

It has a treeView example with a jsonModelBinding

[image: TreeModel with jsonBinding]

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.TreeExpandMulti/preview

Using the list view as it its it's not possible. You would have to extend it witch IMHO would achieve a result quite similar of the tree view component.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using this component I am able to generate Tree view. Currently I wanted to create List View with the same data.

Comment: Please suggest if there is any option to show the checkbox only to the end node of the tree.